# How can i replace nested loop using lapply in R?

Tags: r

Good afternoon ,

I have developped this R function that hashes data in buckets :

```
#   The used packages 
    library("pacman")
    pacman::p_load(dplyr, tidyr, devtools, MASS, pracma, mvtnorm, interval, intervals) 
    pacman::p_load(sprof, RDocumentation, helpRFunctions, foreach , philentropy , Rcpp , RcppAlgos) 


  hash<-function(v,p){
  if(dot(v,p)>0) return(1) else (0)   }

  LSH_Band<-function(data,K ){

  # We retrieve numerical columns of data 
  t<-list.df.var.types(data)
  df.r<-as.matrix(data[c(t$numeric,t$Intervals)])
  n=nrow(df.r)

  # we create K*K matrice using normal law
  rn=array(rnorm(K*K,0,1),c(K,K))
  # we create K*K matrice of integers using uniform law , integrs are unique in each column
  rd=unique.array(array(unique(ceiling(runif(K*K,0,ncol(df.r)))),c(K,K)))

  buckets<-array(NA,c(K,n)) 
    for (i in 1:K) {
      for (j in 1:n) {
        buckets[i,j]<-hash(df.r[j,][rd[,i]],rn[,i])
      }
    }   
  return(buckets)   
}
> df.r
  age height salaire.1 salaire.2
1  27    180         0      5000
2  26    178         0      5000
3  30    190      7000     10000
4  31    185      7000     10000
5  31    187      7000     10000
6  38    160     10000     15000
7  39    158     10000     15000
> LSH_Band(df.r, 3 )
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

The dot function is the scalar product of two vectors.

- My Lsh function takes a row of my data , then it takes a part of the
  obtained row using `df.r[j,][rd[,i]]` . `df.r[j,]` is j-éme row of the
  data.
- `rd[,i]` : rd is a K*K matrix of integers between 1 and ncol(df.r) , each column of the matrix contains only unique integers.
- `rn[,i]` : rn is a K*K matrix that contains values of N(0,1) law.
- In the resulting table , observations are represented in columns . I will have k Rows.  For the last row , i will compute the scalar product between `df.r[j,][rd[,K]]`  and `rn[,K]`. I will obtain 1 if the scalar product is positive.  `rd[,K]` and `rn[,K]` will be used only for the last row in the resulting table and for all observations in that row.

**My question :**

Is it to replace **the loops** with variables i and j by **a lapply function** ?

My real data will be large , this is why i'm asking this question.

Thank you !

Comment: Your code is not reproducible; please include all code (for functions `dot`, `list.df.var.type`) so that we can reproduce your expected output based on the sample data you give.

Comment: @ Maurits Evers , I added the used packages.

Comment: The `dot` and `list.df.var.type` are functions from packages pracma and 
helpRFunctions

Comment: Is there any possible suggestion ? the for loops will make my code slower for high values of n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a bit too long as a comment, so here are some pointers/issues/remarks:

1. First off, I have to say I struggle to understand what `LHS_Band` does. Perhaps some context would help here.
2. I don't understand the purpose of certain functions like `helpRFunctions::list.df.var.type` which simply seems to return the column names of `data` in a `list`. Note also that `t$Intervals` returns `NULL` based on the sample data you give. So I'm not sure what's going on there.
3. I don't see the point of function `pracma::dot` either. The dot product between two vectors can be calculated in base R using `%*%`. There's really no need for an additional package.
4. Function `hash` can be written more compactly as

   ```r
   hash <-  function(v, p) +(as.numeric(v %*% p) > 0)
   ```

   This avoids the `if` conditional which is slow.

---

Notwithstanding my lack of understanding what it is you're trying to do, here are some tweaks to your code

```r
hash <-  function(v, p) +(as.numeric(v %*% p) > 0)

LSH_Band <- function(data, K, seed = NULL) {

    # We retrieve numerical columns of data
    data <- as.matrix(data[sapply(data, is.numeric)])
    # we create K*K matrice using normal law
    if (!is.null(seed)) set.seed(seed)
    rn <- matrix(rnorm(K * K, 0, 1), nrow = K, ncol = K)
    # we create K*K matrice of integers using uniform law , integrs are unique in each column
    rd <- sapply(seq_len(K), function(col) sample.int(ncol(data), K))
    buckets <- matrix(NA, nrow = K, ncol = nrow(data))
    for (i in 1:K) {
        buckets[i, ] <- apply(data, 1, function(row) hash(row[rd[, i]], rn[, i]))
    }
    buckets
}
```

1. Always add an option to use a reproducible `seed` when working with random numbers. That will make debugging *a lot* easier.
2. You can replace at least one `for` loop with `apply` (which when using `MARGIN = 1` iterates through the rows of a `matrix` (or `array`)).
3. I've removed all the unnecessary package dependencies, and replaced the functionality with base R functions.

Comment: 1 / My real data contains categorical values so i should retrieve only the numerical attributes using list.df.var.type.  2/ My Lsh function takes a row of my data ( it takes just a subvector of this row , this is way i used df.r[j,][rd[,i]] ) , then it computes a scalar product with a vector of N(0,1) law. if the scalar product is positif we obtain 1 , else 0.

Comment: @mouad2020 Please add details/clarifications in your main post instead of in comments. That makes it easier for others to extract relevant information. I still don't see the point of `list.df.var.type`. Did you step through your code step-by-step? `t$Intervals` is `NULL`  at least based on the sample data you give. To get only `numeric` columns you can simply do something like `data[sapply(data, is.numeric)]`; no need for an additional package.

Comment: ok.  I'm searching a way to rewrite loops using lapply function.

Comment: @mouad2020 `lapply` is for iterating through columns of `data.frame`s. You're working with `array`s.

Comment: @mouad2020 I've updated my answer with a tweaked version of `LSH_Band`. You really ought to give more context/details involving what `LSH_Band` actually does (in words or with some formulae).

Comment: @ Maurits Evers . Thank you ! I'm working in a classification project and sometimes i found it difficult to express correctly what i'm doing. I had updated my post with more clarification

Comment: Your solution works fine for me ! thank you for your valuable help !

Comment: @ Maurits Evers , Thank you again M.